# Nice-select is not working on Laravel View

Tags: html, css, laravel, view

I was using nice-select on plane HTML that was working fine when I merge HTML with Laravel view nice-select stop working.

> HTML

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
   <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
   <head>
      <!-- Bootstrap , fonts & icons  -->
      <link href="{{ asset('assets/css/bootstrap.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
      <!-- Plugin'stylesheets  -->
      <link href="{{ asset('assets/plugins/nice-select/nice-select.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
      <link href="{{ asset('assets/plugins/slick/slick.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
      <!-- Vendor stylesheets  -->
      <link href="{{ asset('assets/css/main.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
   </head>
   <form action="#" id="apply_now_form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      @csrf
      <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-12 mt-lg-0 mt-8">
         <div class="nice-select gr-text-11 mb-7" tabindex="0">
            <span class="current">Selected Job</span>
            <ul class="list">
               <li data-value="2" class="option">Front End Developer</li>
               <li data-value="3" class="option">Backend Developer</li>
               <li data-value="4" class="option">VueJS Developer</li>
            </ul>
         </div>
      </div>
   </form>
   <link href="{{ asset('assets/plugins/nice-select/jquery.nice-select.min.js') }}">
   <link href="{{ asset('assets/js/custom.js') }}">
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where did you initialize the plugin ?

Comment: In public folder @Saromase

Comment: $(document).ready(function() {
  $('select').niceSelect();
});

Did you use that ?

Comment: Why not use a classic select, and transform it with niceSelect ?

Comment: Because it's a perfect match with its plugin. @Saromase

Comment: @Saromase its not working
$(document).ready(function() { $('select').niceSelect(); });